# How to update table in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to update the table Student_Course in a database in SQL, it runs but I keep getting

> Violation of Primary Key, Cannot enter duplicate

I really just need to update the marks value but need to match it to the CID (Course ID) and SID(Student ID)

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Course SET CID=@CID,  SID=@SID , Mark=@Mark", con))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", cboCID.GetItemText(cboCID.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", cboSID.GetItemText(cboSID.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mark", Convert.ToInt32(txtMark.Text));

                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Mark Added");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two down votes with no reason? This may be a beginner's question, but it is our responsibility to guide him on that as well :)

Comment: You need to update on some criteria. `UPDATE [TABLE] SET [COLUMN] = <VALUE> WHERE [COLUMN] = <CRITERIA_VALUE>`. Otherwise it will try and update all the rows of the table to the `<VALUE>` you passed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"UPDATE Student_Course SET Mark = @Mark WHERE CID=@CID AND SID=@SID"
```

This should be the correct SQL statement because you are trying to update the `Mark` field in your `Student_Course` table based on the `CID` & `SID` of the person.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL Statements Updates all entries in the database and sets the same SID and CID for each row. That is why you get the error.

```
"UPDATE Student_Course SET CID=@CID,  SID=@SID , Mark=@Mark"
```

To Update a specific row where the CID and SID match use:

```
"UPDATE Student_Course SET Mark=@Mark WHERE CID=@CID AND SID=@SID"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did before is `set` the value of the `CID`/`SID` on which you have a `primary key` - Which must be unique.

The sql you are looking for is: (setting the `Mark` by the `CID` and `SID`)

```
UPDATE Student_Course 
SET Mark=@Mark 
WHERE CID=@CID AND SID=@SID
```

And in the code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Course SET Mark=@Mark WHERE CID=@CID AND SID=@SID", con))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", cboCID.GetItemText(cboCID.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", cboSID.GetItemText(cboSID.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mark", Convert.ToInt32(txtMark.Text));

                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Mark Added");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error during insert: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Course SET CID=@CID,  SID=@SID , Mark=@Mark", con))
```

to *(use a [`WHERE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)) clause)*:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student_Course SET Mark=@Mark WHERE CID=@CID AND SID=@SID", con))                              
                                                                     ^^^^^^^
```

Since, you wanted to update the marks value along with a match on **CID** and **SID**.

You previously updated all the entries in your Database. For which you got an error:

> Violation of Primary Key, Cannot enter duplicate

Since, out of CID and SID *(probably this one was set as your primary key)* got a value that was previously set.